How can I use geometry nodes to extrude a tube from two concentric circles that are not connected in any means yet?
I used 2 curve circle nodes to create the concentric rings.
My basic need is to create a tube that I can alter the radius and wall thickness.
I have used curve to mesh nodes before with curve circle and it creates export geometry problems that show up in Unity and Tinkercad.
So this attempt is proving daunting to me.My thinking is to create the 2 concentric circles and join them in a mesh where the circles become inner and outer walls then extrude the filled ring to a required height.
Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

It seems like you might be making things more complicated than they need to be. If you could give more info on the problems you were having for previously just using Curve to Mesh, then we might be able to find a better solution. I am guessing that it is probably a problem with the normals of the generated object.
The below node tree generates a tube of given length and radius just like you are after, but the normals aren't properly all facing out. In the viewport we can turn on Face Orientation to visualise the direction of the normals. The red shows we are looking at the back of a face.


We can use the same node tree setup, but add the Flip Faces to flip the direction of the normals on the original extruded mesh, before joining and merging my distance. Now we have a watertight tube with the correct normals. Is this what you were after?



Thank you.  I was testing the Blender creations to find the best structure creation for importing to Tinkercad. What I found is that Tinkercad import ruins geometry. This proved to be a failure. Unity importing does not. Unity has no problems at all with Blender obj exports to import. My answers were hard won and now I can continue.
